# Engagement plan condition outcome 'no' supports no action?

Tags: engagement-plans

In my Sitecore 8.2u5 instance I am implementing different engagementplans and want to assign actions like sending an EXM campaign email to outcome of condition checks between states.

It seems I can only assign actions on outcome 'yes' and not on outcome 'no'.
Is there a specific reason for this that I am missing, or is this something that is wrong in my configuration?

[image]

As you can see I have an action after condition with outcome 'yes' where I could assign an action. I cannot do this on the No outcome, and had to introduce another weird always true condition to be able to also do an action.

Other then upgrading to Sitecore 9, any other fixes around for this?

Comment: This is 1000% easier in Sitecore 9.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You can't get around it.  If you actually take a look at the Engagement Plans in the Marketing Control Panel, you'll see that a condition only has one field for Next State (when true).  There's none for a false condition state.  So, you have to go through another condition to allow for you to add the "false" state.

Btw, for SC9, Engagement Plans have been deprecated and replaced by Marketing Automation Plans.  Besides the non-Silverlight interface, it also moves away from states, conditions, and actions, although the new concepts are very similar but simplified but also more powerful and extensible.  In the Marketing Automation Plans, there's a Condition that allows for connections on both the true/false.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Just like driving and only turning left, if you loop enough through the Yes's, you can eventually get to a No result, using Yes's. Heh.